# SVM classifer one against all

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

When I run the below mentioned SVM classifier (One against all) code I get the following error at the line : `model{k} = svmtrain(double(trainLabel==k), trainData, '-c 1 -g 0.2 -b 1');`

In matlab:Y must be a vector or a character array.

Can anyone help me?

```
The code is:
%# Fisher Iris dataset
load fisheriris
[~,~,labels] = unique(species);   %# labels: 1/2/3
data = zscore(meas);              %# scale features
numInst = size(data,1);
numLabels = max(labels);

%# split training/testing
idx = randperm(numInst);
numTrain = 100; numTest = numInst - numTrain;
trainData = data(idx(1:numTrain),:);  testData = data(idx(numTrain+1:end),:);
trainLabel = labels(idx(1:numTrain)); testLabel = labels(idx(numTrain+1:end));
```

Here is the implementation for the one-against-all approach for multi-class SVM:

```
%# train one-against-all models
model = cell(numLabels,1);
for k=1:numLabels
    model{k} = svmtrain(double(trainLabel==k), trainData, '-c 1 -g 0.2 -b 1');
end

%# get probability estimates of test instances using each model
prob = zeros(numTest,numLabels);
for k=1:numLabels
    [~,~,p] = svmpredict(double(testLabel==k), testData, model{k}, '-b 1');
    prob(:,k) = p(:,model{k}.Label==1);    %# probability of class==k
end

%# predict the class with the highest probability
[~,pred] = max(prob,[],2);
acc = sum(pred == testLabel) ./ numel(testLabel)    %# accuracy
C = confusionmat(testLabel, pred)                   %# confusion matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the use of the function `svmtrain` from the [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) library with the function of the same name included in Matlab's [Statistics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/support-vector-machines.html).

In the libsvm library, the third input to `svmtrain` is a string that contains command line-like options. In Matlab's version, options are set using Name/Value pairs. The string you use, `'-c 1 -g 0.2 -b 1'`, means cost parameter = 1, gamma parameter of the radial basis function kernel = 0.2, and you are requesting probability estimates. To use the same SVM in the Matlab implementation, I *think* you have to specify the options `'boxconstraint', 1, 'kernel_function' 'rbf', 'rbf_sigma', 0.2`. The Matlab implementation does not support probability estimates though.

But since the code you want to use is apparently based on the libsvm library, the easiest way to make it work would be to install libsvm.